# Подключение к удаленной базе

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

Как подключиться к удаленной бд `postgres` из терминала ubuntu?

Пишу пример данных для входа.

> remote server:

**ip:** 5.10.21.10

**login:** rmylogin

**password:** rmypassword

> postgres data:

**server-url:** http://localhost:8080/text

**db-url:** jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname

**db_name:** dbusername

**db_pass:** dbpass

Нужно подключиться из терминала в `ubuntu`. Напишите плз. на примере этих данных как это сделать.

И вообще непонятно зачем нужен server url, если в качестве сервера будет удаленный сервер, пытался подключиться в Идее, но думаю что проблема в server-url значении, для чего оно надо непонятно.

---

Подключение делается след. образом:

```
$ su postgres
```

и

```
$ psql
```

от пользователя postgres. Как можно залогиниться в одной строчке?

Comment: Похоже, вам нужен `psql` с ключами `-U` и `-h`. Подробности в `man psql`. Но в зависимости от того, как у вас всё организовано, этого может быть недостаточно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. открываете сеанс оболочки на сервере:

   ```
   $ ssh rmylogin@5.10.21.10
   ```

   на предложение ввести пароль вводите `rmypassword`.
2. запускаете в этом сеансе программу *psql* (не понял, что именно в приведённой вами информации является именем базы данных, а что — именем пользователя базы данных, потому не могу подставить конкретные значения):

   ```
   $ psql имя-базы-данных имя-пользователя
   ```

   на предложение ввести пароль вводите `dbpass`.

---

но с большой вероятностью пункт 2 «не сработает» — обратитесь за консультацией по поводу «как там настроено подключение к серверу баз данных postgres?» к администратору базы данных.

---

**дополнение**:

> Подключение делается след. образом su postgres. и psql от пользователя postgres

более коротко:

```
$ su -c psql postgres
```

> Как можно залогиниться в одной строчке?

например, объединить всё в одну команду:

```
$ ssh -t rmylogin@5.10.21.10 su -c psql postgres
```

опция `-t` программе *ssh* в данном случае нужна для отведения терминала (*tty*), который требуется программе *su*.

Comment: Спасибо за инфу. Подключение делается след. образом su postgres. и psql от пользователя postgres. Как можно залогиниться в одной строчке? Переключаться на пользователя postgres и потом конектиться немного затратно по действиям.

Comment: я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Буду рад если поможешь и вот с этим вопросом
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/551679/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%91%D0%94-postgresql